# Creating Trover Style Gallery iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uistackview

I'm trying to create a gallery within my iOS swift app which resembles in style what Trover does, so basically I want to have an array of images, specify a max amount of images to fit within one row, and then I want to dynamically generate `UIImageViews` with a frame size determined by the code to create the collage effect below. I know this can be done in android using `recyclerView`, however I am not sure what the best approach would be for this in iOS, I know I can use TableView, CollectionView or StackView however I'm not sure what the easiest approach to this would be...the way I used `CollectionViews` in the past is that they had a static size for the `CollectionViewCell` hence I'm not sure how to adapt them to this purpose.

[image]

Comment: With UICollectionView, you can use a custom layout. It seems, from your screen shot (I don't use the app, simple speculations), that there are only 2 kind of lines, so you may not even have to create a whole custom layout. Just giving the size of the item, according to it's index row (here, I'd say that every 4 cells, it's the same size), it should be enough.

Comment: Are you suggesting that lets say a block of photos is one `UICollectionViewCell` and depending on how I want the layout to be, I create imageViews inside that cell dynamically? So for example a cell can have 2 `ImageViews` or 4 `ImageViews` etc and I just randomly pick which design I want ?

Comment: I added a sample code for UICollectionView (in Objective-C, but the logic should be the same and there is nothing really complex, except maybe "modulus", but the rest looks like a lot Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From speculation on the image given, we can assume that each 4 items, the layout is the same. So we can use a `UICollectionView` and we *may* (see Note at the end of the answer) just have to override [`collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:) with the following code in Objective-C, but the logic is the same in Swift:

```
CGFloat wholeWidthAvailable = collectionView.frame.size-interspace; //Since we only show 2 item per line, there is only 1 interspace
CGFloat height;

switch (indexPath.row%2)
{
    case 0:
        height = 100;
        break;
    case 1:
        height = 200;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
CGFloat width;
switch (indexPath.row%4)
{
    case 0:
        width = wholeWidthAvailable*2./5.;
        break;
    case 1:
        width = wholeWidthAvailable*3./5.;
        break;
    case 2:
        width = wholeWidthAvailable*3./5.;
        break;
    case 3:
        width = wholeWidthAvailable*2./5.;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
return CGSizeMake(width, height);
```

Note:
The code is not tested (I wrote it here, I don't know if it compile as such).
I explicitly wrote the two switch case, but it clearly can be used in one, since modulo 2 and modulo 4 can be "joined". 
I've chosen 2/5 and 3/5 to fit in width (but you can clearly put the proportion that please you).

Comment: If I wanted to make this more complicated and have for example 4 possible layouts, one with 2 imageviews, 3 , 4 and 5 and alter between them randomly, would it be easier to do this within the collectionViewCell class or within the collectionView delegate methods like you suggested above